# Remote controller for a model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller, sinatra

I have an application which runs in my private network. I want to make an app_controller public but not the whole application. I still want to access my models from app_controller without using any other controller.

As a workaround I have setup a proxy sinatra service which simply redirect requests to app_controller and returns the response that it receives from app_controller.

Is there a way to define a remote controller such that I can access my models as if it's in the same rails application. i.e., controllers and models in different rails apps. or am I approaching it in a wrong way?

Comment: What if you secure your controllers with an ACL component to check whether remote access is allowed?